# Google Chrome Strange Css3 Transition Bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

Im Facing a very strange bug in Google Chrome.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6uY7/)

Here is my Code

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="trans">

    </div>
</div>

body {
    background:green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.trans {
    width: 155550px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform, left, top;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.600s;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;

}
#wrapper:hover .trans {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(-155550px,0,0);
}
```

When you hover on wrapper div and transition starts the background flicks to show transparent area. Any Solution For that bug?. Im using Latest version of Google Chrome on Win8

Thanks

**Update :**
This is what im going to achieve for user who want to know what actually im making

**http://jsfiddle.net/vpdpX/**

Comment: What's the desired effect? Im not necessarily sure translate3d is appropriate

Comment: What is your div so freaking wide?

Comment: @ExtPro I'm facing that issue in a slider when the slide move the transparent background appears, I don't want that background flick

Comment: @Hushme i'm still not sure exactly what behaviour you're expecting / attempting?

Comment: @screenmutt i know its wide but u know, we need that freaking width in sliders with so many slides in it

Comment: Can you post a link to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You don't need a freaky width like that i think you can search another options with white-space and inline-block

Comment: @danko im using this in a slider and each slides show with that way

Comment: @Hushme Actually post what you are trying to accomplish. Even if your pictures are 600px across, that is still 260 pictures! Way too many for a slider.

Comment: @screenmutt ,ok condsider width of 1600px/slide and you have only 15 slides, still you will face that problem

Comment: @Hushme. Then do an image replacement strategy. Where you only have a few images loaded at a time and you swap out the new ones with the ones offscreen.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with you using a width for the div which is obsessively wide.

I'm going to take it what you actually want the div to be 100% of the width of the page, in which case it works.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHXP5/1/)

```
.trans {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform, left, top;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.600s;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;     
}

#wrapper:hover .trans {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
```

**EDIT**

To implement this, I would recommend dynamically adding and removing slides offscreen so that you don't have this issue.

Comment: i want width in pixal im using it in a slider with so many slides in it

Comment: you can try to give a white-space:nowrapt to the silde container and display:inline-block to the slides. then you should be able to use width 100%

Comment: How do you plan on stopping on the other images?

Comment: i have thumbnail gallery when you click on last slide thumbnail  it will go to its relavant slide with that animation

Comment: That's kinda a javascript thing. Why not do the whole slider in javascript? There are a lot of good ones out there already.

Comment: yes im using them good one sliders but thats the bug is present in every slider i still see

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would re-evaluate what you're trying to do and how you're trying to implement it. Given the information provided its hard to help too much -but the width of your div is excessive- any animation applied to collapse it will almost certainly not do so correctly.

That said, you are using the wrong kind of animation, and the wrong properties- you only need to add a transition on width, then change the width on hover. This works with a reasonably sized div **you will only face issues with a div 155550px wide**

### [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHXP5/2/)

CSS

```
body {
    background:green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.trans {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: width 1s; /* Opera */

}
#wrapper:hover .trans {
    width:0px;
}
```

Comment: i want that transition with large width

Comment: Beat me to the wrong transition. I was just updating mine now.

Comment: consider some divs with width of 300px and they are align, you want to show last div on hover

Comment: @Hushme It may help if you can update your code with a practical example? Otherwise we're kindof taking a shot in the dark

Comment: @the slides are align vertically and the wrapper has total width of element when you hover the wrapper translate3d(todivposition,0,0)

Comment: @Hushme sorry I dont understand :( There's just not enough info for me to be able to help I'm afraid

Comment: let me make an example now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vpdpX/ here is example the flick is little now but still it is there

Comment: we cant change the width of slide its freakishly only happening in Google Chrome

Comment: You've lost me, I have no idea now I'm afraid :(

Comment: with that effect im sorry to say that the whole design will be killed